# `each_with_index` not working as I thought

Tags: ruby, arrays

I tried to implement the `each_with_index` method on an array.

```
def display_weapons
  puts "Your current list of weapons are: "
  @weapons.each_with_index do |weapon, index|
    puts "#{index + 1}. #{weapon}"
  end
end
```

I call it as:

```
@weapons = ["Rockets", "Laser", "Photon blaster", "Plasma cannon"]
puts display_weapons
```

and I get the result:

```
Your current list of weapons are: 
1. Rockets
2. Laser
3. Photon blaster
4. Plasma cannon
Rockets
Laser
Photon blaster
Plasma cannon
```

I'm not getting what I thought I would. I just wanted to ask how this method is working. Why do I get the elements twice? Once with the index+1 and once without.

Comment: You are not defining `each_with_index`, you are using it.

Comment: change `puts display_weapons` to just `display_weapons`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby, the last statement of a method is automatically returned from it. `#each_with_index` returns the list you iterate, so you perform `puts` on each element/index in the list, and then you `puts` the result of your `display_weapons` call, which is the list of weapons.

Just call `display_weapons` rather than `puts display_weapons`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you called `puts` with the method, which returns `@weapons`.